Representation $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\to GL_3(Q)$ as composition as irreducible representations
I have the following question to solve:
Let  $\rho:\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\to GL_3(\mathbb{Q})$ be a representation of  $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ defined by
$\rho(3\mathbb{Z})=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \:\;0\;\;  0\\
0\;\;1\;\;0\\
0\;\;0\;\;1
\end{pmatrix}$
$\rho(1+ 3\mathbb{Z})=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \:\;0\;\;  1\\
1\;\;0\;\;0\\
0\;\;1\;\;0
\end{pmatrix}$
$\rho(2+ 3\mathbb{Z})=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \:\;1\;\;  0\\
0\;\;0\;\;1\\
1\;\;0\;\;0
\end{pmatrix}$
Decompose $\rho$ into a direct sum of irreducible representations over $\mathbb{Q}$.
What I did so far: (Following an example of a script I found online)
I calulated the Eigenvalues of the second and third matrix ($\lambda(\rho(1+\mathbb{3Z}))=1$ (mult. 3 )
and for ($\lambda(\rho(2+\mathbb{3Z}))=1$ (mult. 3 ).
Then I calculated the Eigenvector of for this specific Lambda.
$x_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$.
Where $<x_1>$ is a 1-dimensional subrep. Afterwards I took $x_2=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $x_3=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}$, two linear independent vectors. Further I showed that $U_2=<x_2,x_3>$ is closed under $\rho$, composed another rep for $U_2$:
$\rho_2(1+\mathbb{Z})=\begin{pmatrix}0\;\; -1\\
1\;\; -1
\end{pmatrix}$, $\rho_2(1+\mathbb{Z})=\begin{pmatrix}-1\;\;1\\
-1\;\; 0
\end{pmatrix}$
two Blockmatrices. Then I assumed those two matrices dont share the same Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors and is therefore irreducible. But, those two matrices share Eigenvectors (complex ones).
Since I am completely new to Representation Theory, and my course is rushing through this topic I am a bit confused.
How would I continue from here?
Thank you very much!

All those three matrices do share three linearly independent complex eigenvectors. But only one of them ($x_1$) has rational components. Your exercise is specifically about rational irreducible reps. Just show that the span of $x_2$ and $x_3$ has no rational 1-dimensional subspace that would be stable under all three matrices, and you are done.
